# Cannot resolve symbol getReadableDatabase();

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I was writing probably the most simple program to create a Cursor so i could demonstrate a query.I'm stuck with the error "cannot resolve symbol getReadableDatabase()"

PS: I've aldready tries invalidating caches and restarting.

```
    package com.example.arjunrao.databasedemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onclick(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
         String drink_name = (String)editText.getText().toString();

        try{
            SQLiteOpenHelper database = new Database_class(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = new database.getReadableDatabase();
            db.query("DRINK",new String[] {"NAME","DESCRIPTION","FAVORITE"});
        }catch(SQLiteException ex){
           final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("SQLITE EXCEPTION GENERATED");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has to be the `new` in your code. Change this line:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper database = new Database_class(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = new database.getReadableDatabase();
```

to

```
SQLiteOpenHelper database = new Database_class(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
```

Your IDE should have pointed out this error though, your code should have built with errors.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I have the same but it tells me can not resolve symbol Database_class

Comment: @Otema that's because this answer was strictly for his own implementation, and **Database_class** is his own sub-class of androids own **SQLiteOpenHelper**. You can read more about implementing yours [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) or [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)